# How can I make this code more effective using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create 10 in-body links by `<a>` tag of course.  In the demo you can see that the code is too long for only 3 links and I'm sure that there's a way to improve this code.

So, how can I know which link was selected and what can I do with this information?

```
function fillYellow() {
    var paintedDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('painted')[0];
    paintedDiv.style.background = "yellow";
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (paintedDiv.style.background == "yellow") {
            paintedDiv.style.background = "#e5e5e5";
        }
    }, 3000);
}

function fillYellow1() {
    var paintedDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('painted')[1];
    paintedDiv.style.background = "yellow";
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (paintedDiv.style.background == "yellow") {
            paintedDiv.style.background = "#e5e5e5";
        }
    }, 3000);
}

function fillYellow2() {
    var paintedDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('painted')[2];
    paintedDiv.style.background = "yellow";
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (paintedDiv.style.background == "yellow") {
            paintedDiv.style.background = "#e5e5e5";
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/panarupo/1/edit

Comment: You want to be more efficient? Use reasonable indentation!

Comment: There is a tool for lazy guys : http://jsbeautifier.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use a jQuery event handlers with a data-* attribute like

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="fillYellow" data-target=".yellow">Using our site</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fillYellow" data-target=".yellow1">NonUsing our site</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fillYellow" data-target=".yellow2">Blablba our site</a></li>
</ul>
<h2 class="painted yellow">Using our site</h2>
<h2 class="painted yellow1">NonUsing our site</h2>
<h2 class="painted yellow2">BLAbla our site</h2>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.fillYellow').click(function () {
        var $target = $($(this).data('target')).css('background', 'yellow');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $target.css('background', '#e5e5e5');
        }, 3000);
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zAh3H/)

- Add the class `fillYellow` to all trigger elements
- Add a `data-target` attribute to the trigger elements with a selector value targeting the element that has to be highlighted
- Add separate classes like `yellow`, `yellow1`,... etc to the target elements

Answer (score 0):

Give common class for all the links. Then you can use like

```
$(".className").click(function(){ alert($(this).attr("href")); });
```

You dont have to give inline call for each anchor tag

Comment: OP is not using jQuery.

Comment: He's new to JS, and the way jQuery is shown all around here, I'm not surprised if jQ == JS to a lot of newcomers.

Comment: Becuase I thought jQuery can help.
@AnoopJoshi can you upload a fiddle/jsbin? I'm new and I don't know where to place it

Comment: @rolory: jQuery /can/ help, however, you have to call out that you are 1) using it, and 2) want guidance on how jQuery can be used to improve your code.